# Getting error when attempting to save score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following code retrieves the player's score from the Google Play Leaderboard. If the retrieved value is superior to the one already stored on the device, the score is saved.

```
    public void Update()
    {       
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
            "myLeaderboardID",
            LeaderboardStart.PlayerCentered,
            100,
            LeaderboardCollection.Public,
            LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
            (data) =>
            {
                if (data.Valid)
                if (data.Scores[0].value > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore", highScore))
                {
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", data.Scores[0].value);
                    PlayerPrefs.Save();
                }
            });
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting 2 errors on this line `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", data.Scores[0].value);`

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string, int)' has some invalid arguments

error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `long' expression to type `int'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried casting your long to an int explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast `data.Scores[0].value` (which is a `long`) to `Integer`

You can do it quick and dirty like this:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", (int)data.Scores[0].value);
```

Comment: thanks. the error is gone but the new Leaderboard score is not saved. do you know why?

Comment: Have you debugged it and are sure that the correct value is sent to the server?

Comment: don't worry. i fixed it.